# Special count in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hey guys I need bigquery sql to count the elements, but it is kind of special, elements are seperated by some delimiter (for example ^G in my case), and I need the count of split elements. For example:

Input table:

```
origin_column
a^Gb^Gc  
a^Gc  
a^Gb^Gd
```

Output query result:

```
element | count  
a | 3  
b | 2  
c | 2  
d | 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select element, count(*) as `count`
from your_table,
unnest(split(origin_column, '^G')) element
group by element
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]